# python subprocess simulate enter key

Tags: python

I want to make a python script that executes a command using subprocess module.
So thats the first part of the code:

```py
ip = '172.17.0.2
cmd2 = 'smbclient \\\\\\\\%s\\\\netlogon'%ip 
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd2,shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate()
print(out.decode())
```

so the output here is `Enter WORKGROUP\ott0's password: Try "help" to get a list of possible commands.`
but i want to input an enter bcz If it prompts me a `smb :>` after I input 'Enter', it means guest account is enabled and i need this information. Once enter is inputted, i need to execute other commands and need the output in different variables. So the question is how I input in a process already executed with .Popen. ps:my Os is ubuntu 20.04 and my python version is 3.8.10.

Comment: send `b"\n"` in the communicate call

Comment: Console: 'ValueError: Cannot send input after starting communication'

Comment: you can only call communicate() once. If you need to send stuff more than once you'll have to open a pipe and use `.write()` to send the bytes.